# Chain of webservices using camel

Tags: java, web-services, apache-camel

I've got two webservices. Basically one take an input string, and return an xml document. The second take the xml from the first and return an xml document. I'm interested in that second document.

The catch is that I can't modify in anyway how these webservices work, and the input parameter has to be send inside the url (it doesn't work inside the body of the request)

So basically, I want to call a web service with input=body (that's work). Then I want to call the second webservice with input=body returned by the first one.

Here is my camel config:

```
<route>
    <from uri="direct:language-identifier" />
    <toD uri="http://opener.olery.com/language-identifier?input=${body}&amp;bridgeEndpoint=true"/>
</route>

<route>
    <from uri="direct:tokenizer" />
    <setHeader headerName="input"><simple>${in.body}</simple></setHeader>
    <toD uri="http://opener.olery.com/tokenizer?bridgeEndpoint=true"/>
</route>

<route>
    <from uri="servlet:opener-preparse"/>
    <pipeline>
        <to uri="direct:language-identifier"/>
        <to uri="direct:tokenizer"/>
    </pipeline>
</route>
```

My problem is:

- When I use toD in the second webservice to pass the input parameter, I get an invalid character (probably because the data contains new lines)
- When I use the setHeader like in the previous config, the input of the second service is set from the initial data (not the data returned by the first webservice)

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To replace the initial route body with the return value from the webservice call, make sure to empty the route body **before** calling the web service:

```
<camel:setBody>
    <camel:simple>${bodyAs(null)}</camel:simple>
</camel:setBody>
<toD uri="http://your-web-service"/>
```

Comment: This didn't work. Now exchange fail with a NullPointerException. There is really no way to make a dumb chain of two webservices like that?

Comment: When you are using wildcards in your webservice endpoints, e.g. ${body}, transfer your body into the header before setting it to null and change your wildcard to ${header}.

Answer (score 0):

This helps me a lot, had same problem => org.apache.camel.InvalidPayloadException - No body available of type: java.io.InputStream but has value: ....

It expect an String but no Pojo in the Body. Other solution would be =>

```
        <setBody>
            <simple>${header.myValue}</simple>
        </setBody>

        <!-- aufrug dokmanager -->
        <toD uri="myUrl/cxf/myService/operation?parama1=${body}&amp;param2=someVaue" />
```